# Target container is not a DOM element new to this

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to create-react-app I just ran it with npm, now when I run npm start i get this error message

I'm not sure exaclty what is causing this error, so I dont know exactly what to include here for my code, so i'll include my error i'm getting, and the code it is showing me is causing the error?

```
×
Target container is not a DOM element.
▶ 2 stack frames were collapsed.
Module../src/index.js
c:/Users/jaybo/React_basics/react_base/src/index.js:7
   4 | import App from './components/App';
   5 | //import './index.css'
   6 | 
>  7 | ReactDOM.render(
   8 |     <App />,
   9 |     document.querySelector('root')
  10 | )
View compiled
__webpack_require__
c:/Users/jaybo/React_basics/react_base/webpack/bootstrap:781
  778 | };
  779 | 
  780 | // Execute the module function
> 781 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  782 | 
  783 | // Flag the module as loaded
  784 | module.l = true;
View compiled
fn
c:/Users/jaybo/React_basics/react_base/webpack/bootstrap:149
  146 |         );
  147 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  148 |     }
> 149 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  150 | };
  151 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  152 |     return {
View compiled
0
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:292:18
__webpack_require__
c:/Users/jaybo/React_basics/react_base/webpack/bootstrap:781
  778 | };
  779 | 
  780 | // Execute the module function
> 781 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  782 | 
  783 | // Flag the module as loaded
  784 | module.l = true;
View compiled
checkDeferredModules
c:/Users/jaybo/React_basics/react_base/webpack/bootstrap:45
  42 |  }
  43 |  if(fulfilled) {
  44 |      deferredModules.splice(i--, 1);
> 45 |      result = __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = deferredModule[0]);
     | ^  46 |  }
  47 | }
  48 | return result;
View compiled
Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push]
c:/Users/jaybo/React_basics/react_base/webpack/bootstrap:32
  29 |  deferredModules.push.apply(deferredModules, executeModules || []);
  30 | 
  31 |  // run deferred modules when all chunks ready
> 32 |  return checkDeferredModules();
     | ^  33 | };
  34 | function checkDeferredModules() {
  35 |  var result;
View compiled
(anonymous function)
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1:57
This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production.
Open your browser’s developer console to further inspect this error.
```

this is my index.js file, it says the error is from my reactDOM.render line

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './components/App';
//import './index.css'

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.querySelector('root')
)
```

thanks for any help! Let me know if i need to include more code here please

Answer (score 0):

Yes I believe that you have a DOM element in HTML with `id='root'`. So you really need to write the `document.querySelector('root')` as `document.querySelector('#root')`.

`ReactDOM.render` method expects a valid HTMLElement as a second argument, but it is `null` in your case. So do like I said, replace `root` with `#root`.

[`document.querySelector(selectors);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

> A DOMString containing one or more selectors to match. This string must be a valid CSS selector string; if it isn't, a SYNTAX_ERR exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`document.querySelector('root')`

to

`document.getElementById('root')`

and you are good to go.

Also, make sure you have `<div id="root"></div>` in your HTML Template.

Comment: That was it, i used queryselector still but I was missing my #, but elementbyID works too! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Just change the root element with id selector of the container where you want render your react components.
Add any element in the index.html and give it some id n same id selector should be passed document.querySelector("#idselector")